# DiffUtil is passing wrong positions to areContentsTheSame method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I have a list with 25 items with stable ids. When user reach bottom of `RecyclerView` I'm fetching next 25 items and displaying whole list (50, 75 and so on).

`DiffUtil.Callback` is calling `areItemsTheSame` with values `int oldItemPosition == int newItemPosition`, I'm checking ids and they are the same, each call returns true (25 calls). So next call will be series of `areContentsTheSame` and I'm expecting also `int oldItemPosition == int newItemPosition`, BUT `newItemPosition` have always +13...

first calls of both methods looks like below (from own `Log`)

```
areItemsTheSame will return true, positions: 0 0
areItemsTheSame will return true, positions: 1 1
...
areContentsTheSame will return false, positions 0 13
areContentsTheSame will return false, positions 1 14
...
```

after these calls I'm logging changes in `ListUpdateCallback`:

```
onInserted pos: 25 count: 12
onChanged pos: 0 count: 25
onInserted pos: 0 count: 13
```

and after redrawing `RecyclerView` childs I'm seeing completely different items shown with change-type animation on every item (in fact I'm moved a bit to bottom to item 34+, visible items at once: 4)

the question is simple: why?!

Comment: How are you defining your stable id?

Comment: every item/model have `int id` and order of list isn't changing (in fact it may, but above question describes only stable order)

Comment: From my point of view it seems that you get same items again with the same IDs. (stableId). On this case some of your items are updated and some other are inserted. Maybe would be nice to check your recyclerView adapter.

Comment: where I'm getting same items again? old list have 25 items with ids 1...25, new list have 50 items with ids 1...50. `areItemsTheSame` is comparing ids and all 25 "shared" items have same id (in same order), so I'm returning true. I'm 100% shure about same order and ids, this `areItemsTheSame` confirms that

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.Callback.html#areContentsTheSame(int,%20int))

> This method is called only if areItemsTheSame(int, int) returns true for these items.

**oldItemPosition** *The position of the item in the old list* and **newItemPosition** is *The position of the item in the new list which replaces the oldItem*.

Comment: I don't understand.. can you clarify?

Comment: In this case, areContentsTheSame will return false, positions 0 13, I think it is better if you compare contents of oldList[0] and newList[13]

Comment: do I have to hardcode this `13` value...?! `areContentsTheSame` returning `false` obviously in every call because first 25 items on both lists (old size = 25, new size = 50) aren`t changing, their positions also. so why first method is comparing same positions (and returns true for every item) and second got this +13 offset?

Comment: no, not hardcoded. `oldList[oldPosition] and newList[newPosition]`. And as I understand from `ListUpdateCallback` logs, `onInserted pos: 25 count: 12` 12 items inserted to list from 25 to 37. `onChanged pos: 0 count: 25` 25 items changed in list from 0 to 15. `onInserted pos: 0 count: 13` 13 items inserted to list from 0 to 13. So I think there is somewthing wrong while adding items maybe. If you can post your code it will be easier to find what is wrong.

Comment: I've inspected my code and found logical mistake, which probably is causing this misorder... thank you for your help, I will get back to this question if problem persist after may logic fix

Comment: I can confirm that after fixing my logic bug everything is working fine. I'm upvoting your answer as our discussion helped a bit and inspired me to look again at some parts of code, but in fact this is not an answer, so I can't mark it. Thank you, wish you luck :) cheers!